# how enable decorations is VS 2017?

Tags: c++, ide, decorator, visual-studio-2017

what can i do in visual studio 2017 to enamble this wondelfull decoration in a C++ project?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Structure Guide Lines** are not currently available for C++:

> Structure Guide Lines are currently supported for C#, Visual Basic, F#, and XAML files, and for any files supported via TextMate grammars. ([source](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes))

> This feature is unfortunately not available for C++ yet, but it is on our backlog to add in a future update. ([source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/03/06/productivity-power-tools-for-visual-studio-2017/))